# What does skew X/Y do in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

I am just wondering what the exact function of skewX and skewY in [raster constructors](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html) is. According to the documentation linked:

> ST_MakeEmptyRaster — Returns an empty raster (having no bands) of
>   given dimensions (width & height), upperleft X and Y, pixel size and
>   **rotation (scalex, scaley, skewx & skewy)** and reference system (srid).

It seems that altogether `(scalex, scaley, skewx & skewy)` defines `rotation`. But obviously, scalex and scaley also defines the scale operation. This makes me wonder what exactly do these four parameters define.

Is the defined function/transformation equivalent to an affine transformation?

If it's just rotation and scaling, wouldn't it be more efficient to use scalex, scaley and the angle of rotation, e.g. theta?

Comment: Theta does not handle the case when skewx must be different from skewy, I suppose.

Comment: @user30184 I am not sure. scalex and scaley can also account for the difference in the x and y direction. So what do skew{x/y} handle, do you know how they are defined in terms of trigonometry?

Comment: Just guessing but perhaps rotation is not involved but "shear" like in this image https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#/media/File:2D_affine_transformation_matrix.svg.

Answer (score 1):

After rotating a raster, the pixelwidth (x) given is not the real pixelwidth anymore but consists of a vector in x direction (scale) and a vector in y direction (skew). There is a good picture (and somewhat difficult explanation) given over [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file)